# link field is saved as embed field

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I insert `{ LINK Package ... }` field to my document, but when I save and reopen the same document it is replaced as `{EMBED Package}`.

How can this be avoided?

Comment: Does the same issue occur if you go through Insert -> Object -> Link to File directly on the ribbon instead?

Comment: @Adam, if I insert in this way I immediately get `{ EMBED Package }`

Comment: I tried and got a Link field. Are you sure you ticked "Link to File"? What type of external document are you trying to link to and is Word running in compatibility mode? i.e are you working with an older word format such as DOC?

Comment: @Adam, I am working with docx file but in `Compatibility mode`. I am attaching `Visual Paradigm (vpp)` file.

Comment: Can you try different types of files and see if the same thing occurs?